# What is $N(t)$ in the definition $E(t) = z(t)+ \frac{N(t)}{\kappa} $ for an evolute?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I am currently reading up on Evolutes in Differential Geometry and in the definition it gives the equation:

$$
E(t) = z(t)+ \frac{N(t)}{\kappa}
$$

Where $\kappa$ is the curvature. However, in the specific book that I am reading, for some reason there is no definition for N(t). By searching stack exchange I have found the formula to be

$$
N(t)= \frac{ z'(t) \times z''(t) \times z'(t)}{ \Vert  z'(t) \times z''(t) \times z'(t) \Vert }
$$

I was wondering if someone could clear up exactly what this N(t) formula is doing for me? My own intuition says that it is simply a normalised tangent vector of the curve but I am hoping to clarify.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$N(t):= T'/\kappa$ is the unit normal to the given curve (see [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Evolute) ).

If you have Elementary Differential Geometry by O'Neil (revised 2nd edition) then you'll see the evolute appears in question 13 of section 2.4 (page 79), and $N(t)$ is defined at the start of section 2.3 (page 59). Also see a brief discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98796/properties-about-unit-tangent-vector-and-unit-normal-vector)

Comment: ...With a special caution taken for the resp. sign of $\kappa$ vs. orientation of $N(t)$.

Comment: Thank you very much Theo C! I do not have that book but it is available on my university database so I will take a look